# why is Google programmable search engine not displaying on Angular

Tags: angular, search-engine, google-search

I am working on an Angular application and I want to use Google's programmable search engine in /shopping section.
I have included the script tag in my `index.html` file. The following is the html for my `shopping-list.compononent.ts` which is on the route of `/shopping`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="display-4"><span><img src="assets/undraw_empty_cart.svg" alt="Card thumbnail" style="width: 1.5em; height: auto;"></span>Your cart</h1>
      <p class="lead">Manage the ingredients that you want to buy here</p>
      <br/>
      <div class=" col-lg-8 list-group list-group-flush">
        <app-shopping-item *ngFor="let shoppingItem of shoppingCartRecipes" [shoppingItem]="shoppingItem"></app-shopping-item>
      </div>      
      
      <div class="col-lg-4 gcse-search"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the `index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ShoppingApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/96250b37a0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=dc5cfbd31541cbb99"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And for some reason, the search box does not show. On inspect element the div is still present but it is not showing, and its property is not changed by anything to `display: none;`

What is going on here? And what could be a good way to embed google search into an Angular project?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions :

1. Try removing `col-lg-4` from the class set.
2. Add a wrapper div around the class.